# Shell Script para calcular média de tempo de execução

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script, shell

Preciso realizar o mesmo comando 10 vezes e visualizar o tempo médio de execução.

Fiz o script abaixo, porém o mesmo sempre retorna a mesma saída, zero, vide print abaixo.

Poderiam me auxiliar a encontrar o erro? Aparentemente a soma `total=$((total+time))` não esta sendo efetuada com sucesso.

#### Código

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEFORMAT=%R
total=0
for i in $(seq 1 10); do

    time=$(time openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in 1mbfile.txt -out outs/out$i.enc -pass file:private.pem)
    total=$((total+time))
done

avg=$((total/10))
printf "Avg Time: %.4f\n" $avg
```

#### Saída

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Além da resposta abaixo, tem outra opção aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54920113

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que li por aí ([aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360324), [aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786), [aqui](https://mathblog.com/floating-point-arithmetic-in-the-bourne-again-shell-bash/), etc), a aritmética do Bash se limita a números inteiros. Para números de ponto flutuante, é necessário usar outros comandos ou utilitários.

Uma opção é usar o [`bc`](https://ss64.com/bash/bc.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEFORMAT=%R
total=0
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
    time=$({ time seu-comando-aqui &>/dev/null; } 2>&1)
    total=$(echo "scale=4;$total + $time" | bc)
done

avg=$(echo "scale=4;$total / 10" | bc)
printf "Avg Time: %.4f\n" $avg
```

O direcionamento para `/dev/null` é para que a saída do comando não faça parte da variável `time`, e posteriormente pegamos a saída de erro (*stderr*) e direcionamos para a saída padrão (*stdout*) - isso é o que o `2>&1` significa. Fiz isso porque o `time`, [por padrão, manda sua saída para o *stderr*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115988). Isso causava outro problema no seu script, pois a variável `time` estava vazia (apesar da saída desta ser mostrada no console).

Devido a isso, os tempos não são mais mostrados, mas se quiser, basta colocar um `echo $time` dentro do `for`.

Por fim, eu uso `bc` para fazer os cálculos, usando a opção `scale` que indica a quantidade máxima de casas decimais a serem consideradas no cálculo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente ! Obrigado @hkotsubo